# natbib package not showing all bibliography entries in agsm style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

Have been using `natbib` with `plainnat` style and had all entries show but wanted to switch it to Harvard formatting (`agsm` style). However, once I've changed it some entries don't show up any more.

For example,

```
@techreport{lcabc_2022,
  author={Frank Mittelbach and Kim Cheslak and Jim Edelson},
  title={Lifecycle GHG Impacts in Building Codes},
  institution ={New Buildings Institute},
  year={2022},
  month={01},
  URL = {https://newbuildings.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/LifecycleGHGImpactsinBuildingCodes.pdf},
  note = {Accessed: 06 Febraury 2023}
}
```

When its also been referenced in the text and shows up when I change back to plainnat style?

Comment: Welcome! I made a small example with `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`. If I add `\cite{lcabc_2022}` in the document, the bib entry is shown.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Let me reinforce the message of @egreg's comment: I am also unable to reproduce the issue you report to have encountered if I augment your code snippet into a minimally compilable test document. There must be something either in the bib entry in question or in the citation call-out that you haven't reported yet. Are there any error messages in the blg (BibTeX log) file?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@techreport{lcabc_2022,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Kim Cheslak and Jim Edelson},
  title  = {Lifecycle {GHG} Impacts in Building Codes},
  institution ={New Buildings Institute},
  year   = 2022,
  month  = 01,
  URL    = {https://newbuildings.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/LifecycleGHGImpactsinBuildingCodes.pdf},
  note   = {Accessed: 06 February 2023}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\usepackage{xurl}
\let\harvardurl\url % redefine \harvardurl

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{lcabc_2022}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```